# Pass stack install `--flag` to stack run?

Tags: haskell-stack

How do I pass a flag to `stack run` like I'd do with `stack install --flag asd:qwe`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this, so here is my suggested workaround:

Instead of using `stack run ...`, build your application using `stack build` and run the program directly.

So, instead of using

```
# The Problem: This doesn't work because run doesn't recognize --flag

> stack run --flag asd:qwe
```

use the following two-step approach:

1. `stack build --flag asd:qwe`
2. `./path/to/your/executable/<your executable>`

---

If you're using `stack install` instead of `stack build`, stack puts the compiled binary in the `local-bin` directory.¹ [The documentation suggests that you add this directory to your $PATH variable](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#downloading-and-installationhttps://), which means you can just call `<your-executable>`.

The rest of this response assumes that you are using `stack build`.

On my system (Arch linux, May '19, stack 1.9.3.1), stack puts the compiled binary in the `bin`-folder inside the `local-install-root`. (Show it using `stack path --local-install-root`.)

The complete path to the executable should be `<local-install-root>/bin/<executable-name>`

¹ According to [The User guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#install-and-copy-bins) there is regular confusion about the meaning of `stack install`. It's an alias to `stack build --copy-bins`, which just copies the binary to `local-bin-path` after building, which makes it generally available if your $PATH includes `local-bin-path`